# Cannot run anything on Ubuntu terminal, always getting the message: "Starting ChromeDriver 115.0.5790.170...ind() failed: Address already in use (98)"

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

I tried to run ChromeDriver but now i can't open terminal unless in the vs code, and almost everything that i put on the terminal i get the same message:

Starting ChromeDriver 115.0.5790.170 (cc0d30c2ca5577520c8646671513241faa0bc105-refs/branch-heads/5790@{#1923}) on port 9515
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
[1692146403,660][SEVERE]: bind() failed: Address already in use (98)
IPv6 port not available. Exiting...

I already tried to kill the process but i does't work.

Maintain the process is not important, i just want to have the terminal running normal again.

I don't know what else to do